# Using the rc-slider API, how can I set the style of specific dots?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider, rc-slider

I would like to use/modify the rc-slider API to create dots along a slider which have different colors.

It seems that the dotStyle API (docs [here](https://github.com/react-component/slider)) allows you to define a style for *all* dots, but not assign a style to a specific dot. In my app, upon clicking a button, a new rc-slider mark is created. I would like to have different buttons which create marks whose associated dot has a different color. This can be done by manually editing `border-color: green`:

`<div class="rc-slider-step">` 
`<span class="rc-slider-dot rc-slider-dot-active" style="border-color: green; left: 0%;"></span>` 
`<span class="rc-slider-dot" style="border-color: green; left: 0.396825%;"></span>`

Note: this is not the same thing as setting the style of a specific mark point (the text displayed near a dot), but rather setting the style of specific dots.

Answer (score 0):

I was tackling a similar issue and managed to solve it by getting the dots parent container and then accessed its children like so:

`const dots = document.querySelector(".rc-slider-step")?.children || []`
(making sure the element exists and adding a fallback value if it doesn't).

From there you get the child you need and do whatever. In your case I'd guess you'd do something like `dots[dots.length-1]` to get the last element and either add a class or inline style it.